# ValueError: too many values to unpack pgadmin4.11

Tags: windows, tuples, pgadmin-4

I just installed a new version of PGAdmin4.11 on my windows 10 computer.

I'm trying to make a simple selection query but I'm receiving a "ValueError: too many values to unpack" error the Message pane.

Example of query:

```
SELECT *
FROM db.my_table
WHERE field1 = 'attribute1'
```

I could only find information for Python, but not for PGAdmin.
The only thing that I found related to PGAdmin is https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAKKotZRCsJ_MNcKEnJqCN2WAN_dUrMaXQ5s9z_3-2JdakkW2uA%40mail.gmail.com

Can someone, please help me?

BTW, the query works fine on DBeaver.

Answer (score 0):

Please try downloading the latest version of pgAdmin4 and check if the issue has been fixed.
Download [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.12/windows/)

Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.12/release_notes_4_12.html

Looks like it it fixed in new version.